# Real device - nullpointer , Emulator - works

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The original code was taken and didn't modified from Google examples. I saw where emulator shows nullpointer and real device works well. 
I use real HTC0PCV1 API 19
Emulator Galaxy S7 API 25
MinSdk 19

On emulator and real device Play store is updated. Don't understand how to fix on real device. Code is original Google

```
private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

private TextView mStatusTextView;
private TextView mDetailTextView;
private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;

// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.auth_email_password);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
    mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);
    mEmailField = findViewById(R.id.field_email);
    mPasswordField = findViewById(R.id.field_password);

    // Buttons
    findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.email_create_account_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]
}

// [START on_start_check_user]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
// [END on_start_check_user]

private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();

    // [START create_user_with_email]
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END create_user_with_email]
}

private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();

    // [START sign_in_with_email]
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.auth_failed);
                    }
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END sign_in_with_email]
}

private void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    updateUI(null);
}

private void sendEmailVerification() {
    // Disable button
    findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(false);

    // Send verification email
    // [START send_email_verification]
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user.sendEmailVerification()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    // Re-enable button
                    findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(true);

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(EmailAuthActivity.this,
                                "Verification email sent to " + user.getEmail(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(EmailAuthActivity.this,
                                "Failed to send verification email.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END send_email_verification]
}

private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailField.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEmailField.setError(null);
    }

    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        mPasswordField.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mPasswordField.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    hideProgressDialog();
    if (user != null) {
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.emailpassword_status_fmt,
                user.getEmail(), user.isEmailVerified()));
        mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

        findViewById(R.id.email_password_buttons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.email_password_fields).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.signed_in_buttons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        findViewById(R.id.verify_email_button).setEnabled(!user.isEmailVerified());
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
        mDetailTextView.setText(null);

        findViewById(R.id.email_password_buttons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.email_password_fields).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.signed_in_buttons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.email_create_account_button) {
        createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    } else if (i == R.id.email_sign_in_button) {
        signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    } else if (i == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        signOut();
    } else if (i == R.id.verify_email_button) {
        sendEmailVerification();
    }
}
```

}

The error is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.social, PID: 3645
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                  at com.borisruzanov.social.ui.EmailAuthActivity.createAccount(EmailAuthActivity.java:75)
                  at com.borisruzanov.social.ui.EmailAuthActivity.onClick(EmailAuthActivity.java:221)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18599)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5883)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:688)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please be specific about the version of the SDK you're using and the version of Play services on both the emulator and device.

Comment: @DougStevenson HTC Google Play Services- 3.4.12 . Galaxy S7 - Google play services- 11.9.75 ... Compile SDK version 26

Comment: So you're saying that the version of Play on the HTC device is 3.4.12?  That's extremely old, and predates Firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson do we talk about play service or store?

Comment: On the device that is failing, look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.  If you see it, you need to update Google Play services on that device.

Comment: @BobSnyder yes but the device says that it is already updated.

Comment: So on the HTC device, if you go to _Settings > Application Manager_, scroll down and tap on Google Play services, the version displayed is 11.9.75?